# Intended purpose behind the recent Stack Exchange homepage change

Tags: discussion, user-interface, social-networking

Is the revamp of Stack Exchange and realtime update of questions related to any social/marketing plans of Stack Exchange and to an extent CHAOS (External Relations) work? Did the previous page layout prove not be beneficial to users?

[moguzalp](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123836/stack-exchange-is-going-to-be-new-kind-of-facebook-do-we-need-it)* and *maybe others* have noticed a modernization to Stack Exchange which maybe a bit too agressive for those who are conservative.

Changes over the last year

- CHAOS team
- Facebook and Twitter Stack Exchange pages
- Art Director
- Google+ sharing replaced LinkedIn sharing.
- The sharing buttons are shown on the trilogy in addition to the SE 2.0 sites
- Stack Exchange home page revamp
- Realtime update of questions

To some users it seem that these feature changes are pushed out under bias as opposed to requests that may or may not improve the functionality and user experience of the SE engine.

<sub>* I wanted to do a heroic edit on https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/123836/stack-exchange-is-going-to-be-new-kind-of-facebook-do-we-need-it but the vote flood was too strong</sub>

Comment: Heaven forbid they spend their hard-earned VC dollars on anything we didn't personally approve. After all, [who needs progress?](http://user.xmission.com/~msgsl/GSL/37woody.jpg)

Comment: Eeeeek! (Did someone say "Eeeek!"?)

Comment: @Robert: How did you get a picture of my car?!

Comment: I think that you're reading a bit too much into the changes, which is causing you to see things that aren't there. Evaluated independently, none of the changes are a particularly big deal, and I suspect that's exactly how they were evaluated prior to their implementation.

Comment: @moguzalp no problem I was in the middle of editing it when [@balpha](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/revisions/123836/2) crashed the party. The problem with vote parades on meta is there no way to save a post via edits after such a flood. If only closing a question froze the votes temporarily say at -5 to give the OP a chance to redeem himself. Oh well, that's meta for you; murder

Comment: @CodyGray you seem to think that these are my views, I am only helping  moguzalp get clarification because everyone else was getting their downvote fetish on instead of editing it for him.

Comment: @phwd balpha didn't "crash the party", he was being helpful.  And, personally, I didn't downvote because of the OPs trouble with communicating.

Comment: I see, you felt left out of the downvote party. I'm glad you were able to bring it to you, too! :-)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Is the revamp of Stack Exchange and realtime update of questions related to any social/marketing plans of Stack Exchange and to an extent CHAOS (External Relations) work?

...not that I'm aware of.  If we *did* turn into a social network quite a few developers would find the nearest open elevator shaft.

> Did the previous page layout prove not be beneficial to users?

Yes, in fact it was very confusing to new users coming to the network for the first time...these changes aim to improve that new (and existing) user experience.

Comment: @moguzalp - The previous homepage gave you **no idea what our company does, or what the communities are here for**...no matter how "simple" the layout was, this *was* very confusing.  We have lots and *lots* of feedback about exactly this.

Comment: Damnit, SOPA!  Can't find the elevator shaft scene from Die Hard on youtube.

Comment: The redesign looks *really* cool. Kudos to whoever did it.

Comment: @Won't: then may be a bit of "Yippie-Kai-Yay Mother F'n" will cheer you up? http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4XEaeOxqy_4

Comment: You pleasing and adapts to new useless lemmmings and upset old useful respected users.  Nice policy, sure!

Comment: @Lazy - We left the stats view and such available for existing users, we purposefully didn't remove these (see the list view button on the sites page for example, this preference is saved).  Also, the communities need to grow to survive, bringing in new users helps existing users.  ...or were you never a new user?

Comment: @NickCraver - when I new, I *RTFM* and *search* and *grok*, not cry. See my history here, f.e.